# Using SunToolkit for testing swing app - need replacement

Tags: java, swing, awt

I maintain a swing application and some of my testclasses use sun.awt.SunToolkit#flushPendingEvents()

This works fine with java 1.8, but migrating to java 11 breaks it (class invisible).

I think my best option is to find a suitable replacement for this specific method.
If anyone solved this, your insight will be greatly appreciated.

I have searched for answers online but have come up empty.

Comment: [mcve] please - demonstrating the usage of that class, including the stacktrace. That said: for java 11, you can simply loosen the module encapsulation constraints

Comment: It simply won't compile: package sun.awt is not visible
[ERROR]   (package sun.awt is declared in module java.desktop, which does not export it to the unnamed module)

Comment: learn about the java module system - pretty sure there are tons of questions here that will  be helpful, you might find them by searching the error message in your favorite search engine (sry, in a hurry right now - no time for duplicate hunting, will try later :)

Comment: Ty for input:) The quick fix is to use --add-exports for compiler. I was hoping for a better solution tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by exporting the offending classes. Not perfect.

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```